# Is there such a tool for manual testing?

Tags: manual-testing, tools, test-strategy

Is there a tool for manual testing with the following features:

- defining test scenarios (card no. 14, sale) and
- expected results: (Transaction authorized, declined...)

Testing:

- show dialog window with steps to the tester (what should be done: e.g. insert card to ATM, enter pin, etc.)
- check the expected results (Transaction authorized, declined), which were defined in the beginning with data in database.

Comment: Don't really understand what you are asking, do you want a tool to generate all of that or to manage it?

Comment: I use MS-Word (and sometimes Excel).

Comment: I need tool, where can I define the steps for tester with expected results. Then the application tells him what to do. When the test is performed by tester, the result is checked in DB automatically by application.

Comment: So, if I understand your comment, essentially you want a tool that dictates specific instructions to a "tester" to do manually, and then rely on some automated oracle to check the outcome of the test.  Why don't you just automate the tests? In the explanation of your magical tool you don't need a tester...you need a robot.

Comment: @diffper - it's possible to create such a "tool" using your favorite scritping language.

Comment: @BjRollison - It's not possible to automate these tests, because somebody has to operate a device. Exactly I would need robotic arm for inserting card, press button,etc..

Answer (score 2):

I've created a similar tool in the past. I happened to use WinTask, but you could easily use your favorite scripting language.

My need was for some repeated, automation-assisted manual testing across a multitude of browsers during the period where the UI was undergoing a series of rapid changes. I needed these tests to be performed by a contractor will very little experience in our product.

The tester was instructed to fire up the browser if needed, perform the listed steps manually, then press a function key when ready. The script then took a picture of the resulting page, performed the database query, compared the results to the expected results, and moved on to the next step.

Everything was logged for later review by more senior, experienced testers.

We already had the manual steps listed in a document, so it was a pretty trivial process to put them in the script.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I need something like this. I am doing just research of possible solutions. Eventually I will create it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is, as Joe said, something you can write yourself. It's also something that some of the commercial and open source test management tools offer.

The ones I know about are Microsoft Test Manager (with Team Foundation Server) and TestLink. Both allow someone to define tests with test steps as detailed as you want them to be (down to "click the OK button") and expected results at a similar level. Both will guide the test executor through the test by displaying the current test step until the user gives some result and optionally enters more information about the system. Both will store the result in their database (TestLink uses its own database, MS Test Manager uses the Team Foundation Server database).

Comment: Will either of these execute a query and compare the actual results against the expected results, as the final step?

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft Test Manager(MTM) has the features you look for:

Have a look at this screenshot. This is what you get when you run tests in MTM. It

- Shows steps to the tester
- Shows the expected results to the tester (Hope this is what you meant)

[image: MTM Execution window]

Seeing these in the test execution window means that you can

- Define Test Scenarios
- Define Expected results

However, this tool cannot go into a DB and check if the expected results are achieved unless you completely automate the process.

You can also see a window similar to this if you use the Web version of TFS Test Hub to manage your Testing Process.

Note : Image is taken from a [Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/10/17/pausing-and-resuming-test-execution-from-the-test-runner-in-microsoft-test-manager/)

Comment: You think so... Maybe you can cross check that and link to a reference to that we *know* it has that feature? Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Edited the answer. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah, much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [TestAdore](http://testadore.com) to do manual testing. It's very simple to [write a test](http://testadore.com/docs/write-test/) because it has only few elements in the description language.

Regarding the database check, you can [run any program](http://testadore.com/docs/running-programs/) and check the results of it.

Basically, a test could look like this:

```
!
Click here, then there

!run wait
cmd /k mydatabasecheck.exe

?
The database contained "clicked here, then there"
```